# How can I use Applocalization to translate the text inside List in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, localization

How can I use localization to translate the text inside the label property?
`AppLocalizations.of(context)!.chatScreen` without using context.

Or is there any method to use ??

```
class WhatsappFeature {
  final String img;
  final String tooltip;
  final String label;


  WhatsappFeature({required this.img,required this.tooltip,required this.label});
}

List<WhatsappFeature> whatsappFeatures = [
  WhatsappFeature(img: "assets/images/whatsapp_features/split.png", tooltip: "aadbdabdabdab", label: "Chat Screen"),
  WhatsappFeature(img: "assets/images/whatsapp_features/status.png", tooltip: "adgrwhrtwehethth", label: "Main Screen"),]
```

//Widget

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Text(whatsappFeatures[index!].label);}
```

//app_en.arb

```
{
  "appTitle": "whatsup"
}
```

Comment: Why you don't want to use the context?

Comment: Try this Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.whatsappFeatures[index!].label);

Comment: How can I edit app_en.arb file to access AppLocalizations.of(context)!.whatsappFeatures[index!].label

Comment: I think it should be sth like this static Map<String, String> ChatScreen"= {
    "en": "Chat Screen" ",
    "ar": "شاشة التشات ",
  }; ===>>>>>>>>> So then you can save the current locale in another var called for example selectedLocal, so it can be "en" or "ar", then you can call AppLocalizations.of(context)!.whatsappFeatures[index!].label.selectedLocal